# Bash one-liner that takes the output of pidof and passes them as arguments to strace?

Tags: bash, strace

I want to get the PIDs of a given process name and attach to their outputs with strace. I can do this manually like so:

```
$ pidof foobar
1234 2345 
$ strace -p1234 -p2345 -s9999 -e write
```

Great! But I want to automate this from Ansible, so I need to do both these steps in Bash i.e. without the manual conversion of the two numeric PIDs to two `-p` arguments.

I've tried a lot of things like creating an array from the PIDs and trying to join the array with `-p` but once it gets this complex you need to create a function and I don't have a lot of scope for that with an Ansible one-liner.

Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to write a script doing the necessary commands and run that script from ansible?

Comment: Yes that would be possible but not as ideal as avoiding the need to create a script

Answer (score 1):

`strace`'s `-p` accepts a list of PIDs as well, all you need is:

```
strace -p "$(pidof foobar)" -s 9999 -e write
```

Comment: Thanks, I did check the `strace` manpage and I didn't see mention that it supported comma separated PIDs. You prompted me to check the manpage which revealed: -p "`pidof PROG`" syntax is supported." Checkout my answer which avoids the need to use the `-S` option.

Answer (score 0):

`strace` may support `pidof` output in the format of:

```
-p "`pidof PROG`"
```

Following oguz's answer, I determined that the following works:

```
strace -p "`pidof foobar`" -s9999 -e writ
```